# Force Responsive Images to match Parent Element Height?

Tags: html, css, image

I have two elements. One is an H1 tag and the other is an IMG tag. If I have the CSS for the two elements below:

```
h1 {
     font-size: 2em;
}
h1 img {
     max-width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1><img src="icon.png" /> Heading</h1>
```

How can I have the img element inherit the height and resize based on the font-size?

Thank you!

Comment: This is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/hRkFQ/. What were you looking for? Your question isn't very descriptive

Comment: Can't be done without js. Here is a solution using jQuery - http://jsfiddle.net/hRkFQ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `font-size: 1em;` to your `h1 img` tag.

**Edit**

Ooops! Sorry, I mean to say that set height: 1em but mistakenly said to font-size.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
h1 img {
   height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I'm taking @miro demo to take the img.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hRkFQ/3/)

Comment: This doesn't change anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the height to 1em, it will use the font size as the height.

```
h1 img {
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

note that the em measure is relative to the font size of the parent element, therefore `h1 img` at 1em is saying 1 x `h1` font size  ( which is 2em )